# Monthly sequence macro

Tags: sql, macros

I am looking to run the below code, to generate a monthly sequence macro. The below macro brings the sum of CASH_2PLUS and BALS_2PLUS by joining monthly files from the data table.

```
%macro codegen(yymm);
%local month i ;
%let month=%sysfunc(inputn(&yymm.01,yymmdd8));
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TEAM_PERF_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&month,0),yymmn6) AS 
SELECT SUM(A.CASH_2PLUS) AS count_accts_0
%do i=1 %to 11 ;
,SUM(x&i..CASH_2PLUS) AS count_accts_&i
%end;
FROM data.cash_v1_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&month,0),yymmn6) A
%do i=1 %to 11 ;
LEFT JOIN data.cash_v1_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&month,&i),yymmn6) x&i
ON (A.HDR_ACCOUNT_ID= x&i..HDR_ACCOUNT_ID)
%end;
;
QUIT;
%mend codegen ;

%codegen (201612)
```

My results when I run the above script looks like this

```
count_accts_0 count_accts_1 count_accts_2 .......count_accts_10 count_accts_11
    2004         1984        1975                     1543            1448
```

I want the next sequence to add a record under this :

```
count_accts_0 count_accts_1 count_accts_2 .......count_accts_10 count_accts_11
    2011         1999        1954                     1512            -
```

The next sequence

```
count_accts_0 count_accts_1 count_accts_2 .......count_accts_10 count_accts_11
    2043         2002        1999                     -            -

.
.
.
.

count_accts_0 count_accts_1 count_accts_2 .......count_accts_10 count_accts_11
    2078             -            -                     -            -
```

If I call the macro in sequence e.g. `%codegen(201701)` and so on till 201711 then I need the %do loop to run  in decrement (e.g. 1 to 10 , 1 to 9 ...so on till it reaches 1). Basically, I am trying to work out a sequence where the `%codegen(yyyymm)` increases by a month while the %do loop reduce by 1.

I am a beginner trying to learn.

Comment: Which RDBMS is that?

Comment: the RDBMS is Oracle